# How to write "Nosé–Hoover thermostat" in latex?

Tags: math-mode

I want to write following in latex -

**Nosé–Hoover thermostat**

I tried this but it didn't work -

```
Nos$\ {\prime} e$--Hoover thermostat
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  This isn't math.  It's an accented letter in text.  This can be input either as `Nos\`e--Hoover` or directly as `Nosé–Hoover` if your input is encoded as utf-8.

Comment: Why an endash between two names instead of a simple hyphen?

Comment: @barbarabeeton yours didn't work, but I tried "Nos\'{e}--Hoover thermostat" and it worked.

Comment: @Bernard -- An en dash is used when multiple authors are involved.  For relevant examples, see the [AMS Style Guide for Journals](http://www.ams.org/publications/authors/AMS-StyleGuide-online.pdf), page 93.

Comment: Does this appear in a bibliography or a caption?  The rules there may be somewhat more strict than for the main text.  Also, some LaTeX front ends may be more rigid and require braces.  (The plain TeX convention, on which LaTeX is based, does not require, and in fact discourages the use of braces in this situation since there braces inhibit kerning.  LaTeX may have found a way around that limitation; I don't know.)

Comment: @Bernard A Nose-Hoover (with a hyphen) is a device for cleaning up after you use a nose hair trimmer, not a type of thermostat :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main text, just write, “Nosé–Hoover thermostat” (with a Unicode en-dash) and save the file as UTF-8.  Then add to your preamble either the line

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
```

if you’re compiling in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, or

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

If you need to use the legacy toolchain.

You can enable a few more symbols that aren’t in the T1 encoding with `\usepackage{textcomp}`, such as the copyright and Euro symbols.  (You don’t need to do that  if you’re already using the first method, with `fontspec`.)

You can still write this the old-fashioned way as `Nos\'{e}--Hoover`, and with some bibliography packages you might need to.